# Cannot retrieve temporary file created by javax HttpServlet after upload

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have an issue that only occurs when the web application is packed into WAR and installed on a Tomcat server - it does not occur during development.

What I do is:

1. I retrieve `Part` from the `HttpServletRequest`, which is the uploaded file:

   ```
       Part uploadedFile = null;
       for(Part part: parts) {
           if(part == null)
               continue;
           if(uploadFieldName.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getName())) {
               uploadedFile = part;
               break;
           }
       }
   ```
2. I then store this `Part` object for later use (it cannot be used immediately). The code is a bit complicated, but essentially akin to:

   ```
   // List of uploaded files pending
   // List declared as:
   // protected List<Part> uploadedFiles;
   synchronized(this.uploadedFiles) {
       this.uploadedFiles.add(uploadedFile);
   }
   ```
3. Later on, I try to fetch the file from another thread.

   ```
   // Assume that the method is synchronized
   Part reqrievedFile = myUploadService.getFileFromArray();
   synchronized(retrievedFile) {
        doSomething(retrievedFile.getInputStream());
   ```
4. Finally I delete the file 5 minutes after use:

   ```
   retrievedFile.delete();
   ```

When testing in Eclipse, this works well, the file is available and I can process it.

But when this feature was added to the test code and uploaded on test Tomcat server, testers experienced this error:

> IOException: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\work\Catalina\localhost\Projectname\upload_9357ad4d_193f_40fc_96d6_b6e4b9e3c82a_00000001.tmp 
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: I feel like the way that you are storing these files is important for understanding what went wrong. For instance, what is the `uploadedFile` var type?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It's always the original `Part` object I obtained from the `HttpServletRequest`. The only real difference is that they are wrapped in another object and stored in a `HashMap`, but other than that, I'm just working with the part object. I do not create my own temporary files.

Comment: But that's wrong. Those are called temporary files for a very good reason: you aren't guaranteed that it will not be deleted between now and when you'd look for it the second time. If you want to be able to stabilize this behavior, you'd want to actually make a non-temporary files out of those parts.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Is there any guaranteed time frame when the file is safe to use? I couldn't find any good documentation on this...

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head either. Gut feeling says that once RPC connection is closed, then all bets are off regarding those. Closing of connection may indeed be the trigger - you may check that by throttling the processing thread.